# -webkit-background-size doesn't work with jQuery Css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to load a background after the page loads but it seems it does not work as I expect.

My code before in css was:

```
html {
    background: url(<?php echo $this->Cdn->getUrl(); ?>/images/photos/bg-blurred.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #0c1d31;
}
```

Now I try it with jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery('html').css({
        'background-image': "url('<?php echo $this->Cdn->getUrl(); ?>/images/photos/bg-blurred.jpg')",
        'background-size': "cover",
        'background-color': "#0c1d31",
        '-webkit-background-size': "cover",
        '-moz-background-size': "cover",
        '-o-background-size': "cover",

    }); 
});
```

It seems the '-webkit-background-size' and '-moz-background-size' and '-o-background-size' are not working using jQuery.css. The other css properties works fine.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Please add a starting point in code to get a proper and quick answer to your question. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Roy I don't understand what's wrong with my question ?

Comment: Why do you bother since browsers have not needed prefixes for this for quite some time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it was my mistake. I miss some code in my JS...

```
    jQuery('html').css({
        'background-image': "url('<?php echo $this->Cdn->getUrl(); ?>/images/photos/bg-blurred.jpg')",
        "background-repeat": "no-repeat",
        "background-position": "center center",
        "background-attachment": "fixed",
        'background-size': "cover",
        'background-color': "#0c1d31",
        '-webkit-background-size': "cover",
        '-moz-background-size': "cover",
        '-o-background-size': "cover",
    });
```

Is good.

Answer (score 1):

If you try with only "-webkit-background-size":

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

   jQuery('html').css({
      '-webkit-background-size': "cover"
   });
});
```

You'll see that your element will look like this:

```
<html style="background-size: cover;">
```

So this is not your issue.

You should probably look for your url:

```
"url('<?php echo $this->Cdn->getUrl(); ?>/images/photos/bg-blurred.jpg')"
```

If you are using chrome, check in f12 inside the Network's tab, to see if there's not an error.

Comment: No the issue is not there. The background image load well. It's only the issue with the centering (cover) which fails. I've updated my question with the normal css code.